# Local Socket Between Winform And ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, signalr

Local Socket Between Winform And ASP.NET Web Application

I would like to write a chat application between Window Form application and Web application.

I understood that we using Socket like signalR, signalR Core or Web Socket. It's using a middle Hub for forward message.

I wouldn't like to approach this way (Winform send directly data to Web without middle Hub). Whether it's possible?

Comment: Short answer: yes, its possible. Your question however clearly shows that you have a misconception of what problems SignalR actually solves. I suggest to investigate further before starting any real-work using a problematic design

Comment: You can reuse the backend code from the middle Hub and put into your Winform application.

Comment: I saw an application in my company, develop by Vendor. 
It use 1 application get data from Card Reader (Smart Card) to read Citizen ID Card and then send to Web application. I don't know how can web identify which msg is local.

Comment: The Vendor provides me with information, if the application is installed in my computer and I am accessing this website on the same computer. Web and application can communicate with each other through Socket Local.

Comment: I found the root cause. Because it's using Winform application open port socket with role is server side and then, web via http/https with role client. Web will connect to 127.0.0.1:8765 to connect.